# Determine singular value partition

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, singularity

Determine a singular value partition for the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  i \sqrt{6} & -3 i & i \sqrt{3} \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \sqrt{6} & 3 & \sqrt{3} \\
\end{pmatrix}\in M_3(\C).
$$\vspace{2em}

This is how I started, but need help with how to continue:
To determine a singular value decomposition (SVD) of the given matrix $A$, we start by computing the matrix $A^*A$ and its eigenvalues. Then we can use eigenvalue decomposition to find the matrix $V$, and then calculate the matrix $U$ and the singular values.

1. Calculate $A^*A$:
   [
   A^*A = \begin{pmatrix}
     -i \sqrt{6} & 0 & \sqrt{6} \\
     3i & 0 & 3 \\
     -i \sqrt{3} & 0 & \sqrt{3} \\
   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
     i \sqrt{6} & -3 i & i \sqrt{3} \\
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
     \sqrt{6} & 3 & \sqrt{3} \\
   \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
     7 & 0 & 3\sqrt{2} \\
     0 & 9 & 0 \\
     3\sqrt{2} & 0 & 9 \\
   \end{pmatrix}
   ]
2. Calculate the eigenvalues of $A^*A$ by solving the equation $\text{det}(A^*A - \lambda I) = 0$:
   [
   \text{it}\begin{pmatrix}
     7-\lambda & 0 & 3\sqrt{2} \\
     0 & 9-\lambda & 0 \\
     3\sqrt{2} & 0 & 9-\lambda \\
   \end{pmatrix}